# FastFeatureDetector opencv C++ filtering results

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am developing a game bot and using opencv and I am trying to make it detect spikes.

The spikes look like this : 
[image: With no keypoints]

What I tried was using a FastFeatureDetector to highlight keypoints  , the result was the following : 
[image: With keypoint highlighted]

> The spikes are horizontal and change colors.the operation is on a full 1920x1080 screen

So my thinking was to take one of the points and compare to all of the other points X's since I have no way of filtering the result and 6094 KeyPoints the operation took too long. (37136836 iterations).

Is there a way to filter FastFeatureDetector results or should I approach this in another way?

my code :

```
Point * findSpikes( Mat frame , int * num_spikes )
{
    Point * ret = NULL;
    int spikes_counter = 0;
    Mat frame2;
    cvtColor( frame , frame2 , CV_BGR2GRAY );
    Ptr<FastFeatureDetector> myBlobDetector = FastFeatureDetector::create( );
    vector<KeyPoint> myBlobs;
    myBlobDetector->detect( frame2 , myBlobs );

    HWND wnd = FindWindow( NULL , TEXT( "Andy" ) );
    RECT andyRect;
    GetWindowRect( wnd , &andyRect );

    /*Mat blobimg;
    drawKeypoints( frame2 , myBlobs , blobimg );*/

    //imshow( "Blobs" , blobimg );
    //waitKey( 1 );

    printf( "Size of vectors : %d\n" , myBlobs.size( ) );

    for ( vector<KeyPoint>::iterator blobIterator = myBlobs.begin( ); blobIterator != myBlobs.end( ); blobIterator++ )
    {
#pragma region FilteringArea
        //filtering keypoints
        if ( blobIterator->pt.x > andyRect.right || blobIterator->pt.x  < andyRect.left
             || blobIterator->pt.y > andyRect.bottom || blobIterator->pt.y < andyRect.top )
        {
            printf( "Filtered\n" );
            continue;
        }
#pragma endregion

        for ( vector<KeyPoint>::iterator comparsion = myBlobs.begin( ); comparsion != myBlobs.end( ); comparsion++ )
        {
            //filtering keypoints
#pragma region FilteringRegion
            if ( comparsion->pt.x > andyRect.right || comparsion->pt.x  < andyRect.left
                 || comparsion->pt.y > andyRect.bottom || comparsion->pt.y < andyRect.top )
            {
                printf( "Filtered\n" );
                continue;
            }

            printf( "Processing\n" );
            double diffX = abs( blobIterator->pt.x - comparsion->pt.x );
            if ( diffX <= 5 )
            {
                spikes_counter++;
                printf( "Spike added\n" );
                ret = ( Point * ) realloc( ret , sizeof( Point ) * spikes_counter );
                if ( !ret )
                {
                    printf( "Memory error\n" );
                    ret = NULL;
                }

                ret[spikes_counter - 1].y = ( ( blobIterator->pt.y + comparsion->pt.y ) / 2 );
                ret[spikes_counter - 1].x = blobIterator->pt.x;
                break;
            }

#pragma endregion

        }
    }

    ( *( num_spikes ) ) = spikes_counter;
    return ret;//Modify later  
}
```

> I'm aware of the usage of realloc and printf in C++ I just don't like cout and new

Comment: We don't like `new` either, but we've taken a step forwards to `std::vector<>`

Comment: thank you for your reply, will take that into consideration when i will recode this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the spikes actually different sizes and irregularly spaced in real life? In your image they are regularly spaced and identically sized and so once you know the coordinates of one point, you can calculate all of the rest by simply adding a fixed increment to the X coordinate.

If the spikes are irregularly spaced and potentially different heights, I'd suggest you might try :

1. Use Canny edge detector to find the boundary between the spikes and the background
2. For each X coord in this edge image, search a single column of the edge image using `minMaxIdx` to find the brightest point in that column
3. If the Y coordinate of that point is higher up the screen than the Y coordinate of the brightest point in the previous column then the previous column was a spike, save (X,Y) coords.
4. If a spike was found in step 3, keep skipping across columns until the brightest Y coordinate in a column is the same as in the previous column. Then repeat spike detection, otherwise keep searching for next spike

Answer (score 0):

Considering the form of your spikes, I'd suggest [template pattern mathcing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). It seems keypoints are a rather indirect approach.

Comment: Template matching generates me only one result while there are many other results and produces wrong ones as well...